# Error when deploying app with Play framework on Apache 2.2 on port 443

Tags: apache, ssl, https, playframework, playframework-2.2

I configured Apache with SSl.
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

When I need to deploy my app on port 443, I get this error:

...
Play server process ID is 5941
[info] application - Application v2.8 - started on date 2016-03-30 11:51:08.332
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
Oops, cannot start the server.

If I start the app on different port, it works fine. For example:
sudo nohup app_path -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dconfig.file=config_file 2> /dev/null

But I get an error when I start the app on 443:
sudo nohup app_path -Dhttps.port=443 -Dconfig.file=config_file 2> /dev/null

My questions are:
 - Am I missing something? Is there an easy fix for this?
 - How can I see log of the error, because it is not descriptive at all

Comment: Could it be that port 443 is already reserved by some other service?

Comment: Actually port 443 was reserved by Apache server. Changing the port fixed the problem.